# Google Analytics Exception tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have included universal google analytics on the html page:

```
<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Now If I have to add exception tracking, then what is the right way? Shall I add something like this after    ga('send', 'pageview') ?

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    ga('send', 'exception', {
        exDescription: 'JavaScript Error ' + e.message + ' ' + e.filename + ': ' + e.lineno
    });
});
```

Any advice on this will be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the right way, and yes you can definitely do that (and I've done that before).

One thing to consider though is that you'll end up with a fair amount of noise in your reports. `error` events on window can happen for a number of reasons that have nothing to do with the quality of your code. For example, the user could be typing something into the console, a browser extension could be running and messing up, etc.

Anyway, I guess my point is just to say that I've done this in the past and it's proven to be of limited value. That being said, the code you've shown is correct.

Comment: thanks. In that case, what will be the best way to capture the error?

Comment: Put try/catch statements in your code at points where it's possible an error might occur, and track those. Like I said, it's not that your method is bad, it's that it's not 100% within your control, so it won't always be clear if an error is something you should care about.

Comment: thanks. I am going to add try/catch. but after adding those exception tracking, I thought the exceptions will be under events. I dont see any exceptions that way. But if I create a custom report, I can access the exception. Is that how the analytics is designed?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately they're currently not exposed in the interface for web views (they are for mobile views, since exception tracking is more common on mobile), but you can easily access the data using a custom report as you mentioned.